# How does the scope of this private method work?

Tags: java

My question is: how can I see the Tuple `result` in the `process` method if it was created in the `check` method? How am I able to use it there, if it was created in a private method?

```
 public class Problem13 {
    private Tuple<Integer> costs;

    private Tuple<String> names;

    private Tuple<Integer> result;

    private int budget;

    private int minDelta, minCost, totalCost;

    public void process(String fileName) {
        if (!read(fileName))
            return;

        if (budget >= totalCost) {
            System.out.println("You can buy all items");

            return;
        }

        if (budget < minCost) {
            System.out.println("You cannot buy items");

            return;
        }

        minDelta = -1;

        int n = costs.getLength();

        Set<Integer> interval = new IntegerInterval(0, n - 1);

        for (int k = n - 1; k > 0; --k) {
            Combinations<Integer> combinations = new Combinations<Integer>(interval, k);

            combinations.produce((tuple) -> !check(tuple));

            if (minDelta == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (result == null)
            System.out.println("No solution found");
        else {
            int k = result.getLength();

            for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
                System.out.printf("%s ", names.get(result.get(j)));

            System.out.printf("(%d)\n", minDelta);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Problem13().process("data/input13.txt");
    }

    private boolean check(Tuple<Integer> tuple) {
        int k = tuple.getLength();

        int currentCost = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            int j = tuple.get(i);

            currentCost += costs.get(j);

            if (currentCost > budget)
                return false;
        }

        int d = budget - currentCost;

        if (minDelta < 0 || d < minDelta) {
            minDelta = d;

            result = new ArrayTuple<>(k);

            for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
                result.set(i, tuple.get(i));
        }

        return minDelta == 0;
    }
```

Comment: Members of a class (methods, fields, nested types) have full access to other members of that class regardless of its access modifier by design (even `private` ones - otherwise `private` modifier would restrict *any* access to that member making it useless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private` means private *to the class*. So `Problem13` can see anything defined in that class, whether `private`, `public`, `protected` or `package private`.

Also, the access modifier of the method only affects who can call it, not where the results can be seen. For instance, if `result` was defined as a `public` field, *any* class (not just `Problem13`) could see it.

You can find many good breakdowns of access modifiers out there on the Interwebs. [Here's one](https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers).